# How could a web page use a token certificate?

Tags: digital-signature, webcrypto-api

I would like to use a [token certificate](https://safenet.gemalto.com/multi-factor-authentication/authenticators/pki-usb-authentication/) from a browser to sign data. When you plug the token the certificates are accesible in the Windows Certificates Store, but I can't access the certificates from the browser.

I took a look at [Web Crypto API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcrypto-usecases/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) but there are no features for this. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38607119/6371459