# How to Digitally sign a pdf document in the server using USB token in the client's system?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, digital-signature, keystore

I need to digitally sign the PDF document in our server using digital certificate in the usb token. How this can be achieved? Is there any library/api for this?
I tried to access the certificates in the browser as suggested in this
 [link](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/171601/how-do-i-code-an-application-to-pull-the-client-ce.html)

```
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate certChain [] = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate [])request.getAttribute ("javax.net.ssl.peer_certificates");
```

But it is not giving any result. I'm using java. I tried accessing key-store,but it is returning the servers certificates instead of client's certificates. How can i access the client's certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is for SSL authentication, not digital signature. You need a local java application to access USB token and a PDF library like itext or pdfbox.

Itis not possible from browser (except using applets with IE / firefox and old versions of JRE plugin. I do not recommend it). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605661/javascript-key-certificate-from-usb-token/38607119#38607119) and some alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40014020/6371459)