# Read Certificate from USB token in javascript

Tags: javascript, token, digital-signature, private-key

I want to read

> certificate

from `Digital Signature` `(USB token)` **in Javascript**, i need both `public` and `private` key... ? Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: In what environment do you want to do this?  If your answer is "a browser" then you can't do it.

Comment: yes in browser, like IE and chrome etc...

Comment: You have your answer then.

Comment: but it is already being done in a different website, for filing taxes, in govt sites(like cleartax and other Indian Sites, where user just have to connect pen drive and the private key is automatically read and used for filing taxes...)

Comment: Is it using a Java Applet? Anyway check this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - key / certificate from USB Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605661/javascript-key-certificate-from-usb-token). See alternatives here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46194323/6371459

Answer (score 0):

You may use Browser Extension to access USB Token form Javascript.

Extension provides for Signing, Encrypt/Decrypt, Generate CSR, Download Certificate, and many other functions.

Refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885) for Signer.Digital Browser Extension Javascript APIs.